# Exe sproc with TVP and un-tabled parameters in Dapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dapper

I have a sproc (we'll call it *usp_SaveQuestionAnswer*), that inserts/updates an applicant's answer to any given question on an application, that's expecting parameters similar to the following:

```
@answeredQuestionGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@questionGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@applicationId INT,
@applicantID INT,
@answerData tvp_AnswerData READONLY
```

And tvp_AnswerData is defined as:

```
answerGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
answerTypeId INT,
answerValue VARCHAR(300),
answerBoolValue BIT
```

The sproc takes the parameters, and either returns an error, in the form of a string, that the data is invalid (wrong types, null where it shouldn't be, etc.), or returns nothing at all.

The obvious answer to how to do this (according to [this](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/61e965eed900355e0dbd27771d6469248d798293/Dapper.Tests/Tests.Parameters.cs)) would be DynamicParameters, as .Net Core doesn't support DataTables -- build up a DynamicParameters object for tvp_AnswerData, and then a second DynamicParameters object (called *dynamicParamsObject*) for the entire list of parameters, passing the tvp_AnswerData DynamicParameters object into that, and then execute the sproc with the following:

```
var result = _db.Query
(
    "usp_SaveQuestionAnswer",
    dynamicParamsObject,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
);
```

Unfortunately, DynamicParameters doesn't know how to handle a parameter of the DynamicParameters type, as far as I can tell.

Am I doing this wrong?  Is there any way Dapper can handle passing TVP alongside other parameters to a sproc, besides writing out the sql command verbatim, or are my options either to have DB rewrite or to use something other than Dapper (such as a SqlCommand)?

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but it's possible. Below is an example from a random snippet I have:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DeptType] AS TABLE(
    [DeptId] [int] NULL,
    [DeptName] [varchar](100) NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDepartment]
@InsertDept_TVP DeptType READONLY
AS
INSERT INTO Department(DepartmentID,DepartmentName)
SELECT * FROM @InsertDept_TVP;
GO

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=foo");
    conn.Open();

    var x = new DataTable();
    x.SetTypeName("DeptType");
    x.Columns.Add("DeptId", typeof(int));
    x.Columns.Add("DeptName", typeof(string));

    var row = x.NewRow();
    row["DeptId"] = 1;
    row["DeptName"] = "Foo";
    x.Rows.Add(row);

    var row2 = x.NewRow();
    row2["DeptId"] = 2;
    row2["DeptName"] = "Bar";
    x.Rows.Add(row2);

    conn.Execute("InsertDepartment", new { InsertDept_TVP = x.AsTableValuedParameter("DeptType") }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well, or, to go even uglier and loop through the `tvp_AnswerData`

Comment: Unfortunately, DataTable doesn't exist in .Net Core, and the proposed workaround, a SqlDataRecord, isn't a supported parameter type within DynamicParameters.  :(

Comment: Personally I tend to stay away from stored procedures if possible and keep all the logic in code. Good luck.